# CSS pushing content down?

Tags: css

See any page on kranedesign.com

If you decrease the size of your browser horizontally, the main content drops below the navigation.  I'm not sure where or how in the CSS to fix this.  Ideally, I would like it to scale to fit...but even just a horizontal scroll bar would be better.

Comment: +1 on non-table based layout, too many are doing that and taking the easy way out these days.

Answer (score 2):

Your #outer container div should have the following CSS:

```
#outer {
    width: 1160px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Your #aside and #primary are floated with fixed widths, but their container #outer has a width of 100% which means the width changes. So when the browser window width changes to a value less than the width of #aside and #primary combined, then #primary will drop below the #aside div.

Comment: This outer setup is good, because you could then center the content in the browser, or leave it to the left if you'd like.

Comment: Oh, thank you!  It's not ideal -- I'd much rather the page scale to fit, but I'm working with someone else's theme and don't really have the time (or knowledge) to do a major re-work of the CSS.  This solution is a great band-aid.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should have a container div. Like:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="nav"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Then give the container class a overflow : hidden (stretch the container div) and give the container div a width. I think your navigation and content are floated?